# Target parent tag of child which is targeted by data Attribute

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am integrating a third party application into our application , there is one "Share" functionality that i want to hide.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="a" title="broadcast" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="b" title="Share" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="c"  title="favourite" >
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can hide the td using css:nth-child selector but the problem is it hides other elements as well as it has similar HTML skeleton across the application. 
so i targeted the image using its data-attribute but after that not sure how i can get its immediate parent td where i could apply display : none.

I can not modify the third part applications html tags, so there is no scope to add class or id to td and img elements. Only they have provided a customerCss file with which we could hide or change color for branding and all.

Thanks in advance..

here is what i tried to target the img tag

```
img[title = 'Share']:parent {
display : none;
}
```

Comment: You cannot select parent element in css.

Comment: If you can enclose above code into a div with unique id ie.. **<div id="unique_name">**, then you can target this table and its td as child of the new div as CSS properties can be applied on children elements not on parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with CSS.

But you could simply do it with jQuery

**jQuery**

```
$("img[title='Share']").parent().css("display", "none");
```

or

```
$("td:has(img[title='Share'])").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: OP wants to hide parent (not child).

Comment: This will select all img[title='Share'] with parent td. Not td with child img.

Comment: Yeah sry you're all totally right. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Why jQuery? OP hasn't tagged this question with JavaScript, let alone jQuery. OP has also mentioned that they can only modify a CSS file, so unless you propose some way of including jQuery and executing the code you've provided within a CSS file then this answer is meaningless.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Because this is the only way for selecting the parent of an element. There might be a :has selector in the future but at the moment you simply can't do this with CSS.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library in a sea of other JavaScript libraries which all have the functionality to select parent elements. In native JavaScript, you simply need to grab the `parentNode` of the element - no need for jQuery at all. But in OP's case, OP can *only* modify the CSS (as their question states), so this answer will not solve anything. On a side note, the Selectors Level 4 documentation defines an `E! > F` selector, which selects the *E* parent of *F*. In OP's case, `span! > img[title="share"]`.

Comment: With _the only way for selecting the parent of an element_ I didn't mean just jQuery. Of course you could also achieve this with plain JavaScript since jQuery is written in JavaScript but maybe I should have been more precise about this. Also on a side note, the Level 4 documentation also defines a `a:has(>img)` [selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#has-pseudo), which selects all `a` elements which contains an `img` child. In Ops case `td:has(>img[title="Share"])`. But since it's only a draft I think it's not very useful for OP.

Comment: And maybe this script is also useful for someone who has not _only_ access to a CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way of targeting the parent of an element through css. You can however do it via javascript. Here's an example using jQuery:

```js
$('img[title="Share"]').parent('td').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="a" title="broadcast" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="b" title="Share" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="c"  title="favourite" >
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why jQuery? OP hasn't tagged this question with JavaScript, let alone jQuery. OP has also mentioned that they can only modify a CSS file, so unless you propose some way of including jQuery and executing the code you've provided within a CSS file then this answer is meaningless.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I was just providing an option. OP can use vanilla js or any js library for that matter. CSS is not an option here as it cannot target a parent element via the child. Also there are ways for this to work even without including the js in the third party application.

Comment: As I commented on the other answer here, the problem is that OP specifically states that they can **only** modify a CSS file, This answer doesn't help them at all.